# mysql query current month

Tags: mysql

```
$month = (int)$_GET['month']; //201012

table
----------------------
id      date
1       1292376532
2       1292376532
3       1292376532
```

How can I query `201012`'s Data from table?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT *
  FROM `table`
 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`date`), '%Y%m') = '201012'
```

But this query will perform a table fullscan.